# Static library able to link with any other object, regardless of C++ runtime used by that object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, static-linking

I am trying to determine if it is possible at all to create a static library that:

1. Internally uses Microsoft/STL, static release runtime (/MT)
2. Can be linked to objects not using /MT (e.g., Dynamic DLL Release, Static Debug, etc.)

The specific test code I'm trying to get working is as follows:

Header:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    int EncapLibConcatenate(int a, int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Source:

```
#include "EncapLib.h"
#include <string>

int EncapLibConcatenate(int a, int b)
{
    try {
        return std::stoi(std::to_string(a) + std::to_string(b));
    } catch (...) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Linking to the above predictably results in a /FAILIFMISMATCH error when not using /MT for the project that links to the above library. I would like to learn of any compiler / linker options to circumvent this issue. If such do not exist, then any other approaches (such as modifying the .obj COFF files post-build) would also be welcome.

As a side note, I am aware that creating a dynamic library is the idiomatic approach to encapsulating library dependencies; this is a question regarding technical possibilities, not best practices. I have also been able to create a runtime-agnostic static library by eschewing any use of the standard library (restricting to C runtime and win32). This question is specifically about a static library that uses the C++ standard library internally (though pointedly not at its interface).

Comment: Static libraries don't get linked; they are little more than ZIP files holding a collection of .obj files. Actual linking is performed when building an EXE or DLL using this static library. So in the end, you are effectively asking whether it's possible to link an EXE or DLL with both static and dynamic flavor of the C++ runtime. I don't believe it is.

Comment: Rather than modifying .obj files post-build, why not modify them as part of the build? Simply build several versions of the library, with different run-time options, so the consuming project can pick the right flavor. This is the approach the C++ runtime itself takes, as well as libraries like MFC or ATL.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks igor. Your first comment seems accurate. Motivation here comes into play when redistributing an API that must statically link to other dependencies which are statically linked to the runtime. Such a library would lock the consumer into a specific flavor / version of the CRT. also, it's annoying to manage all the different combinations of x86/64 Release/Debug DLL/Static. Many SDKs I interface with just have a single library to link to regardless. Though I suspect they either A) don't depend on C++ runtime at all or B) are import libs for a DLL somewhere.